# Finding a particular nth permutation of a number

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Let's suppose we have a number 123, and we want the exact 3rd permutation of this number. The permutations in order would be {123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321}; so the answer to our question would be 213.

But suppose we have a number that is much bigger, like 1234567, we cannot simply list out all the permutations and count to which one we want.

Is there any way to **MATHEMATICALLY** determine what the nth permutation of a number is?

I have tried to write some code:

```
def permute(s, answer):
    if (len(s) == 0):
        print(answer, end = "  ")
        return
     
    for i in range(len(s)):
        ch = s[i]
        left_substr = s[0:i]
        right_substr = s[i + 1:]
        rest = left_substr + right_substr
        permute(rest, answer + ch)

answer = ""
 
s = input("Enter the string : ")
 
print("All possible strings are : ")
permute(s, answer)
```

However this only shows me all the basic permutations that the number can have, and it doesn't really help me understand the concept.
I have tried to modify the equations for both combination and permutations but they haven't worked either, so any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Sure, just try it.  If there are $N$ letters then, $(N-1)!$ of them begin with any chosen letter, so you can work out what the first digit must be, and then proceed recursively.

Comment: @lulu could u give me an example of what you mean? like with the number 123 I provided? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: As I say, just try it.  If you wanted the fifth one note that $2!=2$ so there are two each beginning with $1,2$ so yours must be the first which begins with $3$, hence $312$.

Comment: @Shaun Thank you for the welcome, let me add some more to the description :)

Comment: You're welcome. That's better! (+1)

Comment: 1) Do you mean that the numbers are ranked in lexicographical order ? 2) Of course, you are limited to $n=9$...

Comment: You can use the factorial number system as described for example [here](https://medium.com/@aiswaryamathur/find-the-n-th-permutation-of-an-ordered-string-using-factorial-number-system-9c81e34ab0c8)

Comment: @JeanMarie To answer you very first question, in our course we consider the permutations from smallest to biggest, and I'm just reading the other post you sent me, Thanks : )

Comment: Even if it doesn't solve optimally your issue, the "next-permutation" algorithm is worth knowing it. See for example [here](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~irani/w17-6D/BoardNotes/22_GeneratingPermsSubsetsPost.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Notice that, in your example, of the $3!$ permutations of $123$, the first $2!$ of them start with $1$, then the next $2!$ of them start with $2$, and the next $2!$ of them start with $3$. This is true in general: of the $n!$ permutations of $12\cdots n$, we can divide them into $n$ blocks consisting of $(n-1)!$ permutations all starting with the same number.

We can use this to write a recursive function in Python that accomplishes what you're asking:

```
def nth_permutation(set_of_nums, n):
    length = len(set_of_nums)
    if length == 1: return set_of_nums
    block = math.floor(n/math.factorial(length-1))
    index = n % math.factorial(length-1)
    modified_set = set_of_nums[:n-1] + set_of_nums[n+1:]
    return [set_of_nums[block]].append(nth_permutation(modified_set, index))
```

Disclaimed: I have not tested this code yet, so it might be buggy. For now just treat it like pseudocode.

Comment: Good approach !

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use the [factorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system). If you use [inversion notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)) to represent the permutations they will be listed in lexicographic order as desired. While you do have to convert from decimal to factorial the process is relatively straightforward.